# Taking cell values in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to take some of the cell values in a table. How to take all at a stretch. Can I assign a class name to those cells and take the values for each of them?

Comment: Can  include `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the cells have the class `content`, you can try by using the default jQuery selector:

```
var cells = $('td.content');
$.each(cells, function(key, cell) {
    console.debug($(cell).html());
});
```

That way, the content of each cell having the class `content` will be written to debug console.

Comment: it say cell.html() not a function

Comment: @dhh `cell` appear to be `DOM` element , not jQuery object having `.html()` method

Comment: @NirmalAnand I amended my code - you can use `$(cell).html()` then.